# Max number of station with hostapd

Tags: hostapd

I search for a wifi interface which accept master mode for create Access Point with Hostapd and can handle at least 40 stations connected (for a classroom)

Hostapd provide the "max_num_sta" but the real limitation is with the hardware?

Do you know wifi interface which accepts a large number of stations in master mode?